# Insert values returned from SQL query to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

The returned structure of an SQL query is: `id | label`

I've created a table with the same structure, how to insert the returned lines to this new table.

Comment: what RDBMS (mySQL, SQL SErver, Oracle?) syntax for the select into varies by DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO new_table (id, label)
<put select query here>
```

Answer (score 0):

insert into SecondTable (id, label)
select id, label from OriginalTable;